# Objective-C: sortDescriptorsDidChange argument?

Tags: objective-c, objective-j

I don't get why sortDescriptorsDidChange takes an argument oldDescriptors if it is never used in the method.

```
- (void)tableView:(CPTableView)aTableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(CPArray)oldDescriptors {
   [result sortUsingDescriptors:[aTableView sortDescriptors]];
   [aTableView reloadData];
}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortDescriptionDIdChange` is a delegate, so you can implement your own behavior for it.

For example, you could use oldDescription along with the new description to manually calculate the changes and provide a nice animation for them. Or to implement specific behavior if the order didn't change etc. etc.

Comment: Is sortDescriptionDidChange automatically invoked when I click on table headers to order the column ? I've only been able to call it explicitly in the code so far. If I click on the column headers, it doesn't work.